# Differentiable A.E. with Positive Derivative Implies Increasing

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, cantor-set

> Claim: Let $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be continuous and differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. If the derivative of $f$ is positive wherever it exists, then $f$ is strictly increasing.

Here's my *fallacious* proof:

> By way of contradiction, suppose there exist $x < y$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \ge f(y)$. I think I can say by continuity (intermediate value theorem?) that $f(x) \ge f(z)$ whenever $z \in [x,y]$.
>   Now, if for every $z \in (x,y]$ we had that $f$ wasn't differentiable on $(x,z)$, then this would contradict the fact that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Hence, there must exist a $z \in (x,y]$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $(x,z)$. By the mean value theorem, there is a $c \in (x,z)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} \le 0$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $f$ must be strictly increasing.

As Ryan Unger pointed out in the chatroom, I haven't given a terribly convincing reason why $f$ should be differentiable on any open interval in $[0,1]$, let alone $(x,z)$. So, my question is twofold. First, is the above claim true; is there any way to salvage my proof?

My next question is, does there exist a continuous function which is differentiable almost everywhere but the set of points of differentiability contains no intervals? I was thinking maybe the fat cantor set could help...?

**EDIT:** I should point out that $f$ doesn't have to have the domain and codomain that I gave it; I only specified those because I'm thinking about Thompson's group $F$.

Comment: See Goldowsky-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Any statement of Goldowsky-Tonelli's theorem I've found says the theorem holds for countable sets. Can it be generalized to sets of measure $0$?

Answer (score 2):

What about $f(x) = 1-\phi(x)$, where $\phi$ is the Cantor function?  $\phi$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$,  is continuous and  non-decreasing, $\phi'(x)$ exists and is equal to $0$ in the complement of the Cantor set (hence a.e.).

Comment: But doesn't the complement of the cantor set contain intervals?

Comment: Yes, it is a countable union of disjoint open intervals.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x-\phi(x)$ instead an you get an actual counterexample, with a derivative that is _positive_ whenever it exists.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Yes!  It's early still and I was misreading "positive"!